# The authenticity of the server when accessing it through a domain name instead of an IP

Tags: ssh, authentication

When I do `ssh username@123.123.123.12`, I log into the server fine. However, if I do `ssh username@example.com`, where `example.com` points to the same IP addrees, I get:

```
The authenticity of host 'example.com (123.123.123.12)' can't be established.
```

If it is the same IP, why can't the authenticity be established?

Comment: Please see [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/421074/ssh-the-authenticity-of-host-host-cant-be-established)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's by design.  When you accept a SSH fingerprint, you're basically associating that fingerprint *with the hostname*, whether example.com, www.example.com or 123.123.123.12.  So the next time, once it's been added to your known_hosts, you know you are safely doing what you have said you are, eg ssh user@***example.com***.

Suppose example.com changes A record, then that fingerprint from example.com will still work; that's not the case if fingerprints were solely associated with IP addresses.  Yes, it's the same SSH fingerprint, used to authenticate the same server with the same key, but the semantics of what you are doing is different.